# the 'hello' sample in eos tutor is not working

Tags: eos

Following the instruction in eos dev website:

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract

first of all, this process stuck forever:

```
eosio-cpp -o hello.wasm hello.cpp --abigen
```

then  I found api generated so break the process.

broadcast the contract to the blockchain is not working either:

```
cleos create account eosio hello EOS75sYBXG6jw89qdsGhcpb6EmLastWwqkEE3n2LbLDz3A94FRobQ -p eosio@active
```

It complains:

```
mutable globals cannot be imported: globalImport.type.isMutable
```

Anyone came across this and how to solve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create new account on cleos using -
**cleos create account eosio hello EOS75sYBXG6jw89qdsGhcpb6EmLastWwqkEE3n2LbLDz3A94FRobQ EOS75sYBXG6jw89qdsGhcpb6EmLastWwqkEE3n2LbLDz3A94FRobQ**

Prior to that import the associated private key(EOS75sYBXG6jw89qdsGhcpb6EmLastWwqkEE3n2LbLDz3A94FRobQ) in the wallet using 
**cleos wallet import --private-key**